# Accessing the digits of a 2 digit long unsigned char (C)

Tags: c

In C, I was curious how to take an unsigned char (That is two digits long) and be able to store the first digit into a different unsigned char, and the second digit into a different unsigned char.

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working? Also, an `unsigned char` is capable of storing more than two digits, so your question doesn't make sense. You need to edit and provide more information as well as showing what you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking decimal digits, you can do this:

```
unsigned char v = 42;
unsigned char tens = v / 10;
unsigned char ones = v % 10;
```

Integer division by ten discards ones; obtaining a remainder of the division by ten drops the rest of the number.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by *digits*.

If you're talking about decimal digits, what you need to do is repeatedly divide by 10 (the base of decimal numbers) and get the remainder in order to extract each digit. If there's only  2 digits, then the first digit can be extracted by just dividing by 10, the second by getting the remainder of dividing by 10.

If you're talking about hexadecimal digits, you can do the same as above, but using a base of 16 instead. Alternatively, you could take advantage of the fact that a byte is made up of two 4-bit nybbles, which can each be represented by a single hex digit. Therefore the upper 4 bits make up the first digit, and the lower 4 bits make up the second.

Here's an example showing both methods:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hex_digits(void)
{
   unsigned char uc = 0xAB;
   unsigned char nyb_hi = uc >> 4;
   unsigned char nyb_lo = uc & 0xF;

   printf("High nybble: 0x%X, low: 0x%X\n", nyb_hi, nyb_lo);
}

void decimal_digits(void)
{
   unsigned char uc = 12;
   unsigned char d1 = uc / 10;
   unsigned char d2 = uc % 10;

   printf("First digit: %u, second: %u\n", d1, d2);
}

int main(void)
{
   hex_digits();
   decimal_digits();

   return 0;
}
```